# Rails 5 ckeditor gem not referencing compiled asset names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use the ckeditor gem in a Rails 5 app.  I added the compile path to config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
```

I can see that it does properly compile.  The problem is, in production, I get 404 errors (works fine in development):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 :assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=GB8C:1
```

This tells me that the ckeditor gem is referencing the hard coded asset name, and not the digest named asset.  Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Why did you do `+= Ckeditor.assets` instead of what README asked [`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/*)`](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#installation)  ?

Comment: I tried this, didn't work (same issue it's not referencing the digest named files)

Comment: gem version? Also you load it from [CDN or GEM vendor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#usage) ?

Comment: ckeditor (4.2.4) and vendor

Comment: how are you referring it in the view, I am assuming here that you did the config correct,,.. like [they said](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#load-editor-from-gem-vendor)

Comment: followed config from instructions, using <%= f.cktext_area :content, copied from instructions.  everything works fine in development, it's only when i deploy that the non digest name is being used

Comment: I faced the same problem a long time ago and ended up using this gem https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets to skip the digest for ckeditor's assets. It's not the best solution, but for my that I never change ckeditor assets the digest is not really needed.

Comment: yeah i think that's what i'll do, i think there's a defect in the gem where if the asset fallback is false, it always references the non-digest link.  @arieljuod if you want credit for the answer pls response as a solution and i'll accept. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem a long time ago and ended up using this gem github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets to skip the digest for ckeditor's assets (and I do the same with other gems that need assets too). It's not the best solution, but for me that I never change ckeditor assets the digest is not really needed.